# Method lines amount. Clean code

Tags: c#

What is the optimal amount of lines in method shold be used?
Curly braces doesn't count. 
What code is better? Code is runing in Main()
//1st

```
string line;
            while ((line = Console.ReadLine()).ToLower() != Break)
            {
                commandAnalyzer.AnalyzeAndRun(line);
            }
```

// or 2nd

```
 RunTextualInterface(commandAnalyzer);

    private static void RunTextualInterface(TextCommandAnalyzer commandAnalyzer)
    {
        while (notBreakCommand())
        {
            analyzeCommandWithHelpOf(commandAnalyzer);
        }
    }

    private static void analyzeCommandWithHelpOf(TextCommandAnalyzer commandAnalyzer)
    {
        commandAnalyzer.AnalyzeAndRun(readNewLine());
    }

    private static bool notBreakCommand()
    {
        return readNewLine() != Break;
    }

    private static string readNewLine()
    {
        return Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    }
```

// result just the same
P.S I am asking cause out teacher said that every method must have maximum 6 lines.(Curly braces dosn't count)

Comment: How are we supposed to determine the "optimal" number of lines? What factors should we use to measure?

Comment: number of lines is irrelevant, the first is better because you can understand it just fine. adding silly long method names is pointless if its clear what is happening EDIT: unless you are paid by number of lines, then the second is always better ;)

Comment: Then ask your teacher this question. Wondering what's the best design isn't necessarily the same thing as what you're expected to do in class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think first approach would be better in this case. Too many method will decrease the readability when the logic involved is not too complex and not that large that it should be a separate method. Also it will make sense to make different methods if this logic has to be used by other parts of program as well. But again as the methods are so small, it doesn't even makes sense to me to make a separate method in this case

Comment: Right. Only extract code into a separate method when you're using it other places in the program. Don't refactor just for the sheer hell of it.

Comment: @Cody, I disagree. Extracting a method *to improve readability* is a good practice even if the method is used only once. In the 2nd example above, most of the methods don't improve readability though, just making the code more complex.

Comment: @Peter: That's precisely the reason I voted to close this question. Because this is not the site to discuss general design principles like that, and because the example given in the question facilitates a very poor discussion of those such principles. I really only meant my comment as a specific response to the code shown in the question, not so much as a general rule. (Also, if it improves readability, that would not be for the "sheer hell of it" ;-))

Comment: @Cody, with this I can fully agree :-)

Answer (score 1):

You want to reduce the amount of code you need to maintain without reducing readability. I like your first answer. Read Steve Yegge on how code size is [Code's Worst Enemy](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2007/12/codes-worst-enemy.html).

Strive to keep everything the reader of your code will need to understand your code as local as possible. Use abstractions (e.g. refactoring stuff to methods) where they help. Avoid abstractions (e.g. inventing new names for operations your reader is already familiar with) where they don't help.

As to the various rules on method sizes: They aren't rules. They are guidelines. Whenever your method gets too long, stop. It could be a sign of a bad design. But it doesn't have to be - use the rule to trigger a closer look at your code.

Develop a sense of style. This will change all the time as you progress. Don't be afraid to update your style all the time - though do try to keep the same style during a project. Try out different styles and gain experience. It is the only true path.

Comment: And what can you add about the rule "just six lines in method" ?

Comment: @Nikita: That it's not a rule, it's a **guideline**. It's meant to convey that methods should remain simple and should be responsible for only one task. It's not a hard rule that's set in stone. Clarity and readability of the resulting code is far more important than adherence to silly rules like that one.

Comment: @Nikita - I think your teacher's 6 line rule is a load of rubbish! Methods often need to be longer than that, there's no sense in splitting them out into loads of tiny methods if it isn't needed. Methods that are hundreds of lines long can be unreadable and are often simplified by breaking them down into smaller methods, but having a strict number of lines (especially as low as 6) is just silly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in that kinda questions, I'd suggest reading:

[**Code Complete 2nd Edition**](http://www.cc2e.com/)

The book has a chapter about that:

"Creating high quality code" -> "How long can a routine be?"